# Unable to delete Cloud Deploy Pipeline from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd

I have done a pipeline creation using newly launch CD tool by GCP, however it seems i cannt delete the pipeline once its created.

I used command as per following:

```
gcloud deploy delete --file=clouddeploy.yaml --region=us-central1 --project=myproject
```

Is there any restriction on deletion since i am getting following error while doing so:

```
$ deploy-quickstart gcloud deploy delete --file=clouddeploy.yaml --region=us-central1 --project=myproject

ERROR: (gcloud.deploy.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Resource '"projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/deliveryPipelines/my-demo-app-1"' has nested resources
```

Comment: Have you tried with `--force` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same command as on a pipeline created with the quickstart and got the same error message as you. As mentioned by Atef H.
in the comments, you need to use the [--force](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deploy/delete#--force) flag as your pipeline has [subresources](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/managing-delivery-pipeline#deleting_delivery_pipelines) (releases/rollouts).